# What 's wrong with my environment IPV6 for ios?

Tags: ios, submit, ipv6

I submitted my first iOS app to Apple Store and the review team has rejected me because:

```
Your app crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.3.4 connected to an IPv6 network
```

My problem is that I can not reproduce the error.

I have a iPhone 5 (iOS 9.3.4) and the environment as shown in the screenshots.

Is my iPhone5 working in IPv6?

[Mac Mini Configuration (Bridge)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcsOW.png)

[iPhone 5 Connection2 (Is it normal to appear that IPv4 assigned?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abLWO.png)

Comment: What research have you done on this topic? Have you watched the free WWDC 2016 video `#714 Networking for the Modern Internet` or the free WWDC 2015 video `#719 Your App and Next Generation Networks`? Have you read the Apple document `Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1

Comment: Basically, stick to Apple's APIs; don't hardcode any IPv4 addresses but use DNS instead and make sure your server supports IPv6. Do your research and testing and come back when you have identified a programming problem.

Comment: @RoboticCat . I read and i wached the video. I have not IP on my code, i always access with DNS. I'm testing but my problem is that in my environment everything is ok, so my ask is ... With the screenshot I have sent, do you think I have well configured the test environment for IPV6 ?. How I can be sure? Is it normal that IPv4 address assigned appears?

Comment: I have no idea but I would have thought not in an IPv6 only setup.

Comment: It's very important to set up the NAT64 test network on your Mac _exactly_ as described in the link that @RoboticCat gave.

Comment: I think i did it exactly as described. Seeing the screenshots, apparently Is this correct?. I did it step by step ... that's my frustration. Perhaps if my mistake is in the web server has different result?, I can only try NAT64 with servers on my LAN ?. I have my dedicated server at 1 & 1. THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my issue. There was an error on my web service server (1&1).

But I never did my application to fail in my test environment. I think it was well set up from the beginning, but no one could confirm.

Thanks for help!